# Error: argument is not interpretable as logical

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I am trying to render a Data table with the following code:

```
output$gt_mapping_table <- renderDataTable(rv$mapping, selection = 'none', rownames = FALSE,
                                               options = list(searching = FALSE,
                                                              paging = FALSE,
                                                              lengthChange = FALSE,
                                                              ordering = FALSE,
                                                              info = FALSE,
                                                              stateSave = TRUE
                                               ),
                                               editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(0))),
                                               server = T
    )
```

but the editable code above only works in Windows. When I try to execute the same package on Linux, I get:

> Error: argument is not interpretable as logical.

I have R Version 3.5.2 on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Are the versions of the used packages the same? Test it with `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Yes, the versions are are same.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `server = T` to `server = TRUE`.

I'm fighting against a similar issue.  In some cases, when you pass a logical to a function (in a list), the function can interpret it as a character.